# C# Difference of output between char return method and object return method

Tags: c#, object, methods, char

I had small problem while solving challenge test where i was comparing output of

```
private object PopS() {
   return stack.Pop();
}
```

and

```
private object DequeueQ() {
   return queue.Dequeue();
}
```

for palindrome words.

Statment:

```
if(PopS() != DequeueQ()) isPalindrome = false;
```

I made breakpoint on this IF statment, provided as input palindrome word "aaaaa" but despite Locals window showing that Pop() returned 97 'a' and DequeueQ() returned 97 'a', statment considered both as "Not equal".

When i changed method casting from object to char, it worked. Output in Locals was identical tho.

Could someone explain me this behavior please? Trying to understand now why 2 same returns from "object" cast was not equal and 2 same returns from "char" cast was equal.

Thanks a lot,
Michael.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one is realted to classes and `Equals(object o)` (overriden `operator ==`) method. Chars are defined something like:

```
public class char : object
{
    private uint value;

    //some more implementation

    override bool Equals(object o)
    {
        //code simplified - no try-catches etc.
        return this.value.Equals((uint) o);
    }
}
```

Now when You are try to compare objects of type `object`, they do not have overriden this Equals method and using default one. And as objects are by default reference type, they are trying to compare reference.

More details on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Also [MSDN - Class and struct differences](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664471(v=vs.71).aspx) will give You some more info.

**What does Your code do?**

It takes 'a' from one side and 'a' from other side. It will create new instance of each (object), something like:

```
char obj1 = 'a';
char obj2 = 'a';
```

If You compare them as chars, You will get true value:

```
obj1.Equals(obj2); //true
```

But if You throw them to object, inner implementation of Equals will check memory (physical memory of PC) and look where is instance of obj1 and where is instance of obj2. If they don't find both at same spot (same memory address - same cell in memory, it will return false)

```
((object)obj1).Equals(obj2); // false
((object)obj1).Equals((object)obj2); // false
(obj1).Equals((object)obj2); // false
```

This can be avoided by casting the variables before calling Equals method.

```
((char)(object)obj1).Equals(obj2); // true
((char)(object)obj1).Equals((char)(object)obj2); // true
(obj1).Equals((char)(object)obj2); // true
```

How would it work with reference equality?

```
public class MyClass
{
    public char Val { get; set; }
}

MyClass obj1 = new MyClass() { Val = 'a' };
MyClass obj2 = obj1;
obj1.Equals(obj2); // true
```

**NOTE: ** I have not used term "Boxing" as @Sweeper does.

Boxing means that the object is casted to be the different one, and getting different behavior related to being handled as other object. (It is closely related to the OOP term polymorphism).

Answer (score 1):

This is known as "boxing".

As you may know, when `==` operator is used on reference types that don't have an overloaded `==`, it compares whether the references are identical. When used with value types on the other hand, it compares the values.

The two `char`s are originally value types, that's why changing the methods to return a `char` makes it work. `'a'` and `'a'`'s values are equal.

But the methods' return types are both `object`. `object` is a reference type. So at runtime, the two `char`s need to become a reference type. This is known as *boxing*. Each `char` is boxed so there are two separate objects, both containing the value `'a'`. But since they are reference types, `==` checks to see if they are the same object, which they are clearly not. Thus, `==` evaluates to `false`.